# Prove that a topological space $X$ is compact if and only if every centered family of closed subsets of $X$ has nonempty intersection.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that a topological space $X$ is compact if and only if every centered family of closed subsets of $X$ has nonempty intersection. I have seen this idea a lot but everyone just assumes it especially when I was in school. I was just curious how one proves it. I was thinking about it and thought about considering the complement and then proceeding since a lot of proofs in topology seem to always favor using an open set.

Comment: by centered family, do you mean a collection of sets with the finite intersection property? If so, we just went over this in class the other day,  but I need to kick my brain into action

Comment: @Alan: Yes, a centred family of sets is precisely one with the finite intersection property: the intersection of any finite subfamily is non-empty.

Comment: I'm tired, but I just found the answer here.  Putting in a comment since it's a link and I don't feel like doing explanation to make it an answer here :) http://planetmath.org/aspaceiscompactiffanyfamilyofclosedsetshavingfiphasnonemptyintersection

Comment: You just take the contrapositive of the standard characterization of compactness in terms of an open cover, and then turn the statements about open sets into equivalent statements about their complements.